# recommended way of showing only entries someone “owns”

Tags: django, django-admin

I am building a small application for a friend, basically it is for invoicing and customer management. If it works for him it might work for some other people who have a one man/woman business like my friend.

I am using the admin interface only. Also I am still quite new to Django.

I found a couple of questions about limiting the information specific users can see and edit in Django's admin interface. some refer to [this article](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/24/admin/).

Having read that it makes sense and it would only be a minor modification to the code I have already writen. My only question is: is this a reccomended way to do this in a comercial application?
Could this method be modified to have an entry owned by a group instead of a single user?

Any thoughts on the pros, cons and alternatives would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is still the recommended way to do it. It's pretty [well documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) as well.

There aren't really any good alternative ways to do what you are trying to accomplish, that I know.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'll go ahead and give it a try then.